# How to match nearest latitude and longitude in Array using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get value (says phone number) based on latitude and longitude in wordpress project. I have set of latitude longitude array like below,

```
$cities = Array(
    "Abilene" => Array("number" => "(222) 333-1111", "lat" => 32.44874, "long" => -99.73314),
    "Akron" => Array("number" => "(111) 111-0000", "lat" => 41.08144, "long" => -81.51901),
....
);
```

I got latitude and longitude using Geolocation plugin. Kindly look on the following code,

```
    //returns nearest value
    function getClosest($search, $arr) {
        $closest = null;
        foreach ($arr as $item) {
            if ($closest == null || abs($search - $closest) > abs($item - $search)) {
                $closest = $item;
            }
        }
        return $closest;
    }


    $latt_array = array();
    $long_array = array();
    foreach ($cities as $keys => $values) {
        if (is_array($values)) {
            foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
                array_push($latt_array, $values['lat']);
                array_push($long_array, $values['long']);
            }
        }
    }
    $match_city = array();
    $latt       = getClosest(49.8, $latt_array);
    $long       = getClosest(-71.032, $long_array);
    foreach ($cities as $keys => $values) {
        if (is_array($values)) {
            if($values['lat'] == $latt ){
                $values['city'] = $keys;
                $match_city['lat']     = $values;
            }
            if($values['long'] == $long ){
                $values['city'] = $keys;
                $match_city['long']     = $values;
            }           
        }
    }
echo"<pre>"; print_r($match_city);echo"</pre>";
```

Above array returns matched latitute and longitude respectively like below.

```
    Array
    (
        [long] => Array
            (
                [number] => (123) 123-1234
                [lat] => 42.35843
                [long] => -71.05977
                [city] => Boston
            )

        [lat] => Array
            (
                [number] => (234) 123-2341
                [lat] => 49.8844
                [long] => -97.14704
                [city] => Winnipeg
            )

)
```

[long] => -71.05977 from long array , [lat] => 49.8844 from lat array will be my matched value here.
 But my  requirement is to match both latitude and longitude in `$cities` array. Is there any other best way to get match latitude and longitude?. How can i match latitude and longitude in my array even in both positive and negative values ?

Kindly advice on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to calculate the actual distance between the location of the user and the location as set in the Array. Here is a great example how to do this in Javascript:

[Calculate distance and bearing between to points in Javascript](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

You will have to rewrite this script for PHP. Than you can simply declare a distance variable and start looping through your array. Whenever the array distance is smaller than the distance declared in the distance variable you save the new distance in the distance variable and save the arrays key to a new variable. Example:

```
<?php
$distance = false;
$array_key = false
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
if( $distance == false || $distance < getDistance($value['lat'],$value['lon']) ) {
$distance = getDistance($value['lat'],$value['lon']);
$array_key = $key;
}
?>
```

Comment: I am trying to use your method. How I can return the value using getDistance or whats the function defintion. can you elaborate some more please.  My code <?php  function getDistance($lat, $long) {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var p1 = new LatLon(Geo.parseDMS('<?php echo $lat; ?>'), Geo.parseDMS('<?php echo $long; ?>'));
                var p2 = new LatLon(Geo.parseDMS('26.71534'), Geo.parseDMS('-80.05337'));
                console.log(    p1.distanceTo(p2));
                //return  p1.distanceTo(p2);
            </script>
    <?php
}

Comment: The javascript code I gave you is just a guide line and can't simply be included within a PHP function (or at least not as an advisable solution). Try to understand the code and what the author is doing (very well described on the page I linked to) and try to make your own PHP function this way.

Comment: Thanks Hidde stokvis, Now i am referring this http://sgowtham.net/blog/2009/08/04/php-calculating-distance-between-two-locations-given-their-gps-coordinates/

Answer (score 2):

To code your own solution, use the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Using the [distance matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) built into google maps will help solve this problem on a much easier and scalable approach.